# Transaction issues in JBPM 5.4.0

Tags: hibernate, jta, jbpm

Our application uses JBPM for handling the workflow but due to some problems we are running into a lot of transaction issues which makes our application unusable. This doesn't happen always and we are not able to find out exactly what causes this. We have tried to synchronize the calling methods so that only one thread works on it at any given time but that is also not helping. Is there anything we are missing when it comes to transaction with JTA and hibernate ?

Its deployed as its own container and is accessible only via a restful interface on top of it.

We are using jbpm 5.4.0
Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not commit transaction
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.doOperationInTransaction(TaskServiceSession.java:1130)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.getEntity(TaskServiceSession.java:1069)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.getTask(TaskServiceSession.java:605)
    at com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.service.impl.CaptisLocalTaskService.getTask(CaptisLocalTaskService.java:153)
    at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler$TaskCompletedHandler.handleCompletedTask(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:251)
    at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler$TaskCompletedHandler.execute(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:234)
    at com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.service.impl.CaptisLocalTaskService$SimpleEventTransport.trigger(CaptisLocalTaskService.java:325)
    at org.jbpm.task.event.MessagingTaskEventListener.triggerPayload(MessagingTaskEventListener.java:76)
    at org.jbpm.task.event.MessagingTaskEventListener.handleEvent(MessagingTaskEventListener.java:92)
    at org.jbpm.task.event.MessagingTaskEventListener.taskCompleted(MessagingTaskEventListener.java:109)
    at org.jbpm.task.event.TaskEventSupport.fireTaskCompleted(TaskEventSupport.java:49)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.postTaskCompleteOperation(TaskServiceSession.java:569)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.taskOperation(TaskServiceSession.java:495)
    at com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.service.impl.CaptisLocalTaskService.complete(CaptisLocalTaskService.java:79)
    at com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.service.impl.WorkflowServiceImpl.completeTask(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:388)
    at com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.service.impl.WorkflowServiceImpl.process(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:143)
    at com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.controller.WorkflowController.process(WorkflowController.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to rollback transaction
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskLocalTransactionManager.rollback(TaskLocalTransactionManager.java:77)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.endTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:110)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.doOperationInTransaction(TaskServiceSession.java:1118)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskLocalTransactionManager.rollback(TaskLocalTransactionManager.java:70)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends on what you are doing with the framework, for example: com.jpmc.rdt.captisflow.service.impl.WorkflowServiceImpl.completeTask(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:388). What is that doing? I guess that you are probably mixing things up in how the interactions with the task services goes. Are you sure that there are not two methods calling at the same time an action on top of the task? 
When you said that the exceptions makes the application unusable, why is that? Are you propagating this exceptions to the user? Most of the time if there is a concurrency issue, one operation will succeed and the other(s) will fail, pushing you to retry all the failed operations.

Comment: Hi, I think the app becomes usable because of the singleton nature of the entity bean this can be controlled by changing the bean scope, so that even if the bean goes bad a new instance can be created. Also this is all synch and one method calls its own interaction.